# Extra pixels when splitting space between two elements

Tags: css, css-calc

I have a block element with two children, and I'll like them each to occupy half the space, minus a fixed-size gap between them.  This should be easy with `calc()`:

```js
var left = document.getElementById("left");
var right = document.getElementById("right");
var info = document.getElementById("info");

var offset = 5;
function toggleStyle() {
  if (offset === 5) {
    offset = 7;
  } else {
    offset = 5;
  }
  info.innerHTML = right.style = left.style = "width: calc(50% - " + offset + "px);";
}

toggleStyle();
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: green;
}

#left, #right {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#left {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#right {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>
<button onclick="toggleStyle()">Toggle</button>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

In the above snippet, I have a 300px parent with children that should be `50% - 5px` = 145px wide, plus 5px margin each.  This means that the two children, plus their margins, should occupy exactly 300px.  When I set it up this way, they wrap.  If I subtract an extra 2 pixels per child, they appear to fill the space exactly, even though they only measure 148px each (including margin).  Where are the extra pixels coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the white space between the left and right divs.

It will work if you remove the white space between them, i.e.:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div><div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Working snippet:

```js
var left = document.getElementById("left");
var right = document.getElementById("right");
var info = document.getElementById("info");

var offset = 5;
function toggleStyle() {
  if (offset === 5) {
    offset = 7;
  } else {
    offset = 5;
  }
  info.innerHTML = right.style = left.style = "width: calc(50% - " + offset + "px);";
}

toggleStyle();
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: green;
}

#left, #right {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#left {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#right {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>
<button onclick="toggleStyle()">Toggle</button>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div><div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ::sigh:: Man, some days I really hate HTML.

Comment: @Coderer Its often the simplest of things that cause the worst problems! :) For future reference, this happens with "inline-block" display, but you can remove the white space manually or HTML comments work too. e.g. `<div id="left"></div><!-- as much space as you want here! --><div id="right"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

**Flexbox** can do that

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}

#left,
#right {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}

#left {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS Grid** can also do that.

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

#left,
#right {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```